# Label overwrites Link action

Tags: html, css, label

I got a decent problem yesterday evening. I was thinking about adding labels on anchor links, so i can "display" which anchor was clicked on.

I generate the code dynamically, but here's the result:

```
<a href="#info"><label><input type="radio" name="tab" value="Information">Information</label></a>
<a href="#connect"><label><input type="radio" name="tab" value="Connect">Connect</label></a>
<a href="#players"><label><input type="radio" name="tab" value="Players">Players</label></a>
<a href="#contact"><label><input type="radio" name="tab" value="Contact">Contact</label></a>
```

This results in a set of "tab" headers.

My problem: The links can not be clicked.
The labels work just fine, the `<a>` tags won't trigger.
Same when i switch the order of `<layer>` and `<a>`.

EDIT: by the way: i don't want to use any javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done. You are trying to do two actions (changing radio button, navigating page content) from user's single click.

Comment: I didn't knew that html has that restriction. Thanks for telling me :)

Comment: Figured out something interesting. Buttons will still call their actions, so could it be concidered a bug?